# Dropdown menu in javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, menu, dropdown, prompt

My question is that how can I use dropdown menu in javascript prompt?
I have tried the below code:

```
var dressTypeSelection = "<select id="dressType">
                        <option value="Bridal">Bridal</option>
                        <option value="Event">Event</option>
                       </select>";
var myPrompt = prompt(dressTypeSelection);
```

It is taking the tags as string and placing the output and this is unwanted. 
I want to have a dropdown in prompt. Is there anyway out of this problem? 
Thanks in advance, 
Regards.

Comment: dropdown as in the values inside it  ?

Comment: AFAIK you can't have a dropdown in window prompt.

*A prompt dialog contains a single-line textbox, a Cancel button, and an OK button, and returns the (possibly empty) text the user entered into that textbox.*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

I think that you're best bet at this point would be to implement a modal with whatever content you want.

Answer (score 2):

The regular alert/prompt dialogs don’t support HTML-elements, what you can do is use modal windows.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your interest. Modal doesn't stops the page execution. Basically, i am prompting a value and then page manipulates the prompt input and execute.